# Can not create a view with v$parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I need create a view and I am doing a UNION ALL in this View but it say I dont have permission. The view is like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW exemple_view AS      
    SELECT 'Version', v.banner, '' as VALUE_EXEMPLE FROM v$version v
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'cursor_sharing', v.value, 'EXACT' FROM v$parameter v where v.num = 1492
```

I'm logged with system user, so I'm sure permission is not the problem, and the union work out of the view, the permission problem apear only to create the view. If I run the query like this work perfectly:

```
SELECT 'Version', v.banner, '' as VALUE_EXEMPLE FROM v$version v
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'cursor_sharing', v.value, 'EXACT' FROM v$parameter v where v.num = 1492
```

Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

And if I create the view like this it work fine. without the v$parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW exemple_view AS
  SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 'Version', v.banner, '' as VALUE_EXEMPLE FROM v$version v
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Version', v.banner, '' as VALUE_EXEMPLE FROM v$version v
    ) t
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<del>You don't have permission to select from `v$parameter`.</del>

It gave me another kind of error, complaining about the first column that has no column name specified: `ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias`

Try to give it one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW exemple_view AS      
SELECT 'Version' AS "Version", v.banner, '' as VALUE_EXEMPLE FROM v$version v
UNION ALL
SELECT 'cursor_sharing', p.value, 'EXACT' FROM v$parameter p where p.num = 1492;
```

Comment: I said I have permission, I can select it (when is not inside the view), just cant create a view with the select